# ROS-Tf-Message too old

Tags: ros, robot-localization, laserscan, ros-noetic, tf-tree

an external localization package is performing localization between the map and base_link frames. There is a lidar attached to the laser frame, which is connected to the base_link, and it is also publishing data. There is a discrepancy between the map and laser frame. When I select "map" as the fixed frame in Rviz, I receive the "Message removed because it is too old" error from the lidar topic. When I set the fixed frame to base_link or the scan frame, the scan data starts to arrive, and the same error begins to come from other topics related to the map. The Tf tree is as follows. Can you assist with this?

[image: Laser Scan Error image]
[image: TF Tree]

[image: TF Tree After setting]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the computers in your ros system need to have the OS provide an accurate time-of-day clock. This is accomplished by enabling the NTP service on each computer.

Comment: The clock of the other computer was wrong. I adjusted the time, and the error disappeared. I added the new TF tree among the question photos, is there any anomaly in the tree?

Comment: The 2nd TF tree looks OK.